# Core Data - Save entity with relationship but without object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, swift

Im using `Core Data`

How do I save a `child` who has a `parent`, but only referencing the `Father`, without saving the `father`.

Example:

I have a son who has a father. But I want to save only the child object. What about the father, I just want to reference it.

Comment: Saving in `Core Data` saves the entire `managedObjectContext`. If parent is an entity in the same context. Any changes to it will be also saved.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that if you have marked some attributes as transient they will never get stored in the disk. It may not be applicable here for you, but just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about saving a reference, but not the object, what does the reference that you're saving refer to? When you save a reference, you're saving a reference *to something*.

A relationship can be used both ways

son.father = father is the same as father.son = son in a one-to-one relationship. Setting son.father = someFather would also "save"/set the inverse relationship of father.son = someFather. The object of father and the object of son would not change, only the relationship.

Comment: Yes, I save SON refer to FATHER. But dont save object FATHER

Comment: I just want to make sure we're on the same page. Are you saving the Father object somewhere else? I'm asking because if you want to save a reference to the Father object, you have to save that object elsewhere. Then, when you save the Son object, you save the value of the primary key for the Father (perhaps its ID or Name) in the Son's reference variable.

Comment: Yes, I save the object Father, and need add one Son to this father without duplicate Father object

Answer (score 0):

When you set a relationship in Core Data you are not specifically setting an object. You are assigning a relationship to an existing object. If the related object does not exist then the relationship would be nil.

Comment: Yes, but i need save one SON with one saved FATHER.